# How to install tar file (jhead) on Mac or Linux machine

Tags: linux, terminal, osx, tar, download

I'm new to Linux and tar balls and was wondering how to properly install them on a Mac or Linux machine. I would prefer to know how to install on a mac but I just need some help understanding them. I want to install [jhead-2.97.tar.gz](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) and I download the zipped source tar ball, yielding a folder containing a myriad of files. I know this is a silly question, but how do I properly install this file on my machine in the Terminal/LXTerminal?

`jhead` is a command tool that is used to extract from an Exif jpeg file in the Terminal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the source

```
wget "http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/jhead-2.97.tar.gz"
```

Untar the source

```
tar xzf jhead-2.97.tar.gz
```

Or, get and untar the source in one step

```
curl "http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/jhead-2.97.tar.gz" | tar xz
```

Now you have a directory called `jhead-2.97`. Enter that directory and run `make`.

```
cd jhead-2.97
make
```

This will compile the code and link an executable for you called `jhead`.

Some makefiles have install targets. This one does. To install the executable,

```
make install
```

You'll probably need to run that as root. Now your program is installed and ready for use.

---

In this case, the install target looks like this:

```
cp jhead ${DESTDIR}/usr/local/bin/
```

If you ever run into a program without an install target in its makefile, just know that you have to get any executables into `/usr/local/bin` and any libraries into `/usr/local/lib` (or other appropriate locations.) Sometimes there are also other files you have to worry about such as documentation files (e.g. man pages), configuration files, etc.

Comment: Is "make" a linux command, terminal says the command isn't found?

Comment: `make` is packaged with most major Linux distributions. MacOS doesn't come with it; you'll have to install Xcode from the [App Store](http://www.apple.com/osx/apps/app-store.html) to get it.

Comment: I already have it, but how is that the missing link? Do I need to install everything through Xcode?

Comment: Xcode provides an implementation of `make`. Try running `/Applications/Install Xcode.app`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6767528/1655874).

Comment: That got me half way there, I was able to run, but this only gave me this error when running "make instal" (also not quite sure what to do with"/Applications/Install Xcode.app") make install
cp jhead /usr/local/bin/
cp: directory /usr/local/bin does not exist
make: *** [install] Error 1

Comment: What verson of MacOS are you using?

Comment: 2012 10.8.2 (Lion)

Comment: When I run that line I get this prompt 'install cp jhead ${DESTDIR}/usr/local/bin/
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...'

Comment: I believe you are supposed to copy the binary to `/Applications`, but I am not entirely sure. On most GNU/Linux machines, the appropriate location for the binary is `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`. MacOS has a different directory structure though.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman /Applications/ is just used for application bundles. /usr/local/bin/ doesn't exist by default, but it is also used by homebrew, pip, and easy_install, and as a location for command line utilities installed by graphical applications.

Comment: How do you deal with adding to `$PATH` on the Mac? For example, I am using your method to install bazel (http://www.bazel.io/docs/install.html#mac-os-x) and it says as a final step: If you ran the Bazel installer with the `--user` flag as above, the Bazel executable is installed in your `$HOME/bin` directory. It's a good idea to add this directory to your default paths, as follows:

`$ export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
You can also add this command to your ~/.bashrc file.`

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 4.3 moved make to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make`. You can install make to `/usr/bin/` by downloading the command line tools package from Xcode's preferences or from [developer.apple.com/downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads) (which requires a free developer account but not Xcode).

If `make install` results in an error like `cp: directory /usr/local/bin does not exist`, just run `mkdir /usr/local/bin/`.

You could also install [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) and run `brew install jhead`.

Answer (score 1):

In 2021, homebrew doesn't recommend using the default `/usr/local/bin` for Apple Silicon or similar architecture.  For M1 `arm64` processors running (Big Sur, Monterey and later) homebrew recommends using `/opt/homebrew/bin`.

Brew recommendation for using `/opt/homebrew` can be found on [the Homebrew installation page](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)