# Installing tar.gz file with no install target

Tags: bash, tar, path, bashrc

I have tried a few answers, namely:

[How to install tar.gz files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175718/how-to-install-tar-gz-files)
[Installing tar.gz file which has no configure, install, and readme file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215304/installing-tar-gz-file-which-has-no-configure-install-and-readme-file)
[How to install tar file (jhead) on Mac or Linux machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74350/how-to-install-tar-file-jhead-on-mac-or-linux-machine/74353#74353?newreg=afdcd78c6981496c92c47e6bc98a61b2)

I am trying to install a specific version of bazel via http://www.bazel.io/docs/install.html#mac-os-x, but using the `tar.gz` file within the `0.2.2b` section of https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases.

The readme file links to the docs in the Github which are not specific about installing tar.gz files and ensuring your `$PATH` is updated. I was surprised to see not very clear instructions in general on this for the web.

I unzipped the file and see:

[image]

How can I go about this process and get myself up and running with `0.2.2b` version of bazel? Homebrew would have been easier but it doesn't allow for older versions of bazel.

Comment: You have in root of archive script, named compile.sh Have you try it?

Comment: Yes this seems to do something, and my command line prints the following after running `sh compile.sh`: `-e INFO: You can skip this first step by providing a path to the bazel binary as second argument:
-e INFO:    compile.sh compile /path/to/bazel
-e -n   Building Bazel from scratch`. What is the "path to the bazel binary"? Where I want bazel to be installed? If so what parameters do I need to set so `Install Bazel to the $HOME/bin directory on your system and set the .bazelrc path to $HOME/.bazelrc..`

Comment: or, is the path to the bazel binary just the path to the unzipped folder I am in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tar.gz` file contains the uncompiled source code. The documentation states, to compile the code you should invoke `./compile.sh`.

However, you can also simply use the pre-compiled `installer-darwin*.sh` at:

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.2.2b/bazel-0.2.2b-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh

The documentation suggested that you will need to install Oracle's Java 8 Development Kit (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and XCode (https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/).

Once the requirements are installed, you can install bazel via command line:

```
bash /path/to/bazel-0.2.2b-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh --user
```

Comment: That's nice put

Comment: I didn't know you could install Darwin.sh files on a Mac OS, thanks.